# Передача не объявленных переменных в функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код, в который мы передаем пустой массив и должны положить через функцию, значения из-за того что i за функцией не объявлена ее приходится объявлять, после чего m[i] в функции всегда берет 0 элемент, как можно этого избежать?

Текущий вывод: [5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1]

Желаемый вывод: [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 5]

```js
let m = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1];
let n = [];

let i = 0;

function forOutMatLab(arr, expression) {
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    arr.push(expression);
  }
}

forOutMatLab(n, m[i] + 1 * 5);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что Вы хотите получить?

Comment: Чтобы я мог forOutMatLab(n, m[ i ] + 1 * 5); передать эту i в цикли она уже там обрабатывалась, в текущем коде в функцию передается не m[ i ], а m[ 0 ] из-за того что приходится объявлять переменную вне функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, чем вы тут занимаетесь. Никакой функции передавать `expression` вообще нет смысла, используйте `array.map(el => el *5);` и всё. Математическое выражение тоже сомнительное, я здесь записал три варианта понимания выражения.

```js
let m = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1];

let n = m.map(item => item *5);
let o = m.map(item => (item + 1)*5);
let p = m.map(item => item + 1 *5);

console.log(n);
console.log(o);
console.log(p);
```

А здесь вообще получаем результат без создания переменной. Не то, что объявления нечитаемой функции:

```js
let m = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1];

console.log(m.map(item => item * 5));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let m = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1];
let n = [];

function forOutMatLab(arr, expression) {
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    arr.push(expression(m[i]));
  }
}

forOutMatLab(n, a => a + 1 * 5);
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как должен получиться желаемый вывод: [5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1]

Мне кажется вы апшиплись.

В примере ниже каждый элемент исходного массива умножается на 5:

```js
let m = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1];
let n = [];

let i = 0;

function forOutMatLab(arr, expression) {
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    arr.push(expression(m[i]));
  }
}


forOutMatLab(n, el => el * 5);
console.log(n);
```